# SQL query for Group By as inner query

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table like below

TestDetails

```
Submitted_on                      Subject    Submitted_By
3/4/2020 7:45:26 PM               English       Shyam
3/4/2020 9:45:26 PM               English       Rahul
3/5/2020 9:45:26 PM               Arabic        Rahul
3/4/2020 8:45:26 PM               French        Yash
3/4/2020 7:45:26 PM               Spanish       John
3/4/2020 6:45:26 PM               Spanish       John
```

I want to select latest submission for each subject from above table.
The output should be :

```
 Submitted_on                     Subject    Submitted_By
3/4/2020 9:45:26 PM               English       Rahul
3/5/2020 9:45:26 PM               Arabic        Rahul
3/4/2020 8:45:26 PM               French        Yash
3/4/2020 7:45:26 PM               Spanish       John
```

I have tried like below
But getting the output as

```
 Submitted_on                    Subject    Submitted_By
3/4/2020 7:45:26 PM               English       Shyam
3/4/2020 9:45:26 PM               English       Rahul
3/5/2020 9:45:26 PM               Arabic        Rahul
3/4/2020 8:45:26 PM               French        Yash
3/4/2020 7:45:26 PM               Spanish       John


SELECT MAX(Submitted_on),Subject,Submitted_By FROM TestDetails GROUP BY Subject,Submitted_By
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the below query

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY subject ORDER BY subject DESC) duplicates, * 
    FROM TestDetails
)
SELECT submitted_on, subject, submitted_by FROM CTE WHERE duplicates = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filtering.  Here is one method:

```
select td.*
from testdetails td
where td.Submitted_on = (select max(td2.Submitted_on)
                         from testdetails td2
                         where td2.subject = td.subject
                        );
```

For performance on larger data sets, you want an index on `testdetails(subject, submitted_on)`.